# jquery cycle not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I am using jquery cycle. It worked if it has multiple images. with one image its not working. also not displaying caption. Here is a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnLtc/). thanks

Slider with multiple images are working.

```
<div id="main">
        <div id="slideshow" class="pics">
            <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Beach 1" />
            <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Beach 2" />
            <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Beach 3" />
            <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach4.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Beach 4" />
            <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach5.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Beach 5" />
            <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach6.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Beach 6" />
            <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach7.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Beach 7" />
            <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach8.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Beach 8" />
        </div>
        <p id="caption"></p>
</div>​
```

Comment: Why exactly would you need a slideshow plugin for one image ?

Comment: Are you just looking to have the caption display in instances where there will be only one image? Or do you expect cycling effects to occur with a single image?

Comment: @adeneo its dynamic. Its depend upon user. they can upload one or more images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this before the cycle call:

```
if ($("#slideshow img").length == 1) {
    $("#slideshow img").clone().appendTo($("#slideshow"))
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jXZDX/)

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to achieve this without having to check the length is to setup the caption for the first image prior to the cycle call:

**Update:**

To use an img's alt when it isn't the item actually being cycled:

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/4Ts3T/7/

```
$(function() {
    $('#caption').html($('#slideshow img:eq(0)').attr('alt'));
    $('#slideshow').cycle({
        fx:       'fadeZoom',
        timeout:   2000,
        after:     function() {
            $('#caption').html($('img', this).attr('alt')); // get nested img's alt
        }
    });
})​
```

**Original Answer:**

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/4Ts3T/2/

```
$(function() {
    $('#caption').html($('#slideshow img:eq(0)').attr('alt'));
    $('#slideshow').cycle({
        fx:       'fadeZoom',
        timeout:   2000,
        after:     function() {
            $('#caption').html(this.alt);
        }
    });
})​
```

Comment: You have to add the title you want in the alt attribute of each image.  I've updated the jsfiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/4Ts3T/5/

Comment: I fixed your jsfiddle not realizing it had a different nesting than mine.. You need to search for the img b/c you are actually cycling the a tags instead of images.  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/4Ts3T/7/